# Fitting ActiveXcontrols in sheet to cell size

Tags: excel, vba

There are several Active controls placed on a Worksheet (Comboboxes, Textboxes and Listboxes). The shapes have also been linked to cells. I need to resize the shapes so that they fit/aligns with the cell size. How do I do this using VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you adjust the height and the width of an ActiveX control. I am taking the example of a `textBox`

```
Dim rng As Range

With [Sheet1] '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set rng = .Range(.TextBox1.LinkedCell)

    .TextBox1.Width = rng.Width
    .TextBox1.Height = rng.Height
End With
```

**Followup from comments.**

> As I stated earlier, there are several different types of ActiveX controls in the sheet. I am looking for generic code that will loop through the Shapes collection (without specifically naming the shapes) and align the shape sizes to those of the linked cells. –  user1955215 12 mins ago

If you want to use shapes then use this.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim shp As Shape

With ActiveSheet
    Set shp = .Shapes("TextBox1")

    Set rng = .Range(shp.OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell)

    shp.Width = rng.Width
    shp.Height = rng.Height
End With
```

Comment: In the immediate window, I type
?Activesheet.Shapes("Combobox1").name
It shows: 
ComboBox1
When I type:
?Activesheet.Shapes("Combobox1").linkedcell
Error 438 is displayed.

Comment: Replace `Sheet1` in my code with the codename of the sheet where the activex control is.

Comment: Thanks. Your code does work. As I stated earlier, there are several different types of ActiveX controls in the sheet. I am looking for generic code that will loop through the Shapes collection (without specifically naming the shapes) and align the shape sizes to those of the linked cells.

Comment: Thanks, Siddharth. I have taken the cue from your code. Specifically, "shp.OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell" and modified my code to make it generic

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to record macro?

```
Worksheets("worksheet_name").Shapes("ActiveX_control_name").Width = number

Worksheets("worksheet_name").Shapes("ActiveX_control_name").Height = number
```

Edit:

How about this?

```
Worksheets("Worksheet_name").Shapes("ActiveX_control_name").TopLeftCell.Address
```

Comment: I have already linked the shapes to single cells. Am struggling to get the address of the linked cell programmatically. If I can get that, then I can find the dimensions of the cell and set the same for the shape.

Comment: @user1955215 It is not excacly showing which linked cell it is. However it shows in which cells it lies.

Answer (score 0):

Select your Active Control Object (Combobox, textbox etc) and Goto "Format" on Ribbon - In the arrange box you would see **Align** with a dropbox next to it. Click it and select **"SNAP TO GRID"**.

In case of multiple object, press F5 - Special - Objects.

In case if you looking to do this via code, record the macro and amend results as requried.

Comment: Tried resizing the shape to fit the grid using the User Interface as shown above. The shape remained unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
Sub resize_controls()
Dim ct As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
For Each ct In ws.OLEObjects
    ct.Top = ws.Range(ct.TopLeftCell.Address).Top
    ct.Left = ws.Range(ct.TopLeftCell.Address).Left
    ct.Height = ws.Range(ct.TopLeftCell.Address).Height
    ct.Width = ws.Range(ct.TopLeftCell.Address).Width
Next ct
End Sub
```

This will capture active x controls I don't know about any other objects.